# An alternative to a list of SlidingDrawers

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

Hi I am developing an application that needs to display list of items. Clicking (or Tapping) on an item should display a description text of the item right below the item. I am talking about something like a vertical [accordion](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/?p=1.1.3).

I want them dynamically created (created in code rather than the XML). That part was completed with ease. I inflated *multiple SlidingDrawer in a LinearLayout* to accomplish it.

But the problem is only one SlidingDrawer is displayed in the activity. This was accomplished by giving fixed heights to SlidingDrawer. This approach will not hold as I mentioned above that the list of items is dynamically generated and also the area in the activity where the description of the item must come remains blank.

I am now looking for alternative views for accomplishing this. As I am a beginner in Android Development I cant find any that will work in android versions 2.3 and later.

Comment: About how many items are you talking?

Comment: @Luksprog : The number of items are also dynamic. They could range from 0 to 30. They are recieved as json response to an Http Request.

Answer (score 0):

You can always take a look at the SlidingMenu. The project can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). I guess you need to modify the behaviour a bit.

Comment: The project seems pretty good one.

But it does not serve my purpose as I have only a single list of multiple items and tapping one the items should display a Layout or a TextView describing the item tapped.

The menu item works like a single accordion handle.